# The 'default' dialect with current database version settings does not support in-place multirow inserts

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have data in a list of dict，i tried to insert the data into my db then i get error **sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: The 'default' dialect with current database version settings does not support in-place multirow inserts.**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine,Table,Column,String,Integer,MetaData,ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists,create_database,drop_database
from sqlalchemy.orm import join

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:268454@localhost:3306/sqlalchemy")
conn = engine.connect()

if database_exists(engine.url):
    drop_database(engine.url)

create_database(engine.url)

metaData = MetaData()

userTable = Table("user", metaData
    , Column("Id", Integer, primary_key = True)
    , Column("Name", String(25)))

orderTable = Table("order", metaData
    , Column("Id", Integer, primary_key = True)
    , Column("UserId", Integer, ForeignKey("user.Id"))
    , Column("Desc", String(250)))

try:
    metaData.create_all(engine)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

users = [
    {"Id": 1,
    "Name": "user1"},
    {"Id": 2,
    "Name": "user2"},
    {"Id": 3,
    "Name": "user3"},
    {"Id": 4,
    "Name": "user4"}
]

orders = [
    {"Id": 1,
    "UserId": 1,
    "Desc": "desc1"},
    {"Id": 2,
    "UserId": 1,
    "Desc": "desc2"},
    {"Id": 3,
    "UserId": 2,
    "Desc": "desc3"},
    {"Id": 4,
    "UserId": 2,
    "Desc": "desc4"},
]

sql = userTable.insert().values(users)
print(sql) #this line causes the exception

conn.execute(sql)

sql = orderTable.insert().values(orders)
print(sql)

conn.execute(sql)

sql = userTable.select()
print(sql)
returnUsers = conn.execute(sql)
print(returnUsers)

sql = orderTable.select()
print(sql)
returnOrders = conn.execute(sql)
print(returnOrders)

conn.close()
```

**update：without print(sql) it can works perfectly.**

Answer (score 7):

Try if it works if you iterate over the list of dicts and pass in the dicts individually. What you are trying to do uses a special syntax, that is not available in all dialects.

```
for user in users:
  sql = userTable.insert().values(user)
  print(sql) #this line causes the exception

  conn.execute(sql)
```

Admittedly the [sqlalchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.values.params.*args) states, that the MySQL backend should support this. Personally I would not rely on something that is not portable or non-standard and stick with one insert call per row, or the explicit `bulk_insert` methods.

**Edit Regarding print statement**

As I mentioned in my comment, the method print calls on this representation of a query is not dialect aware.
You can however retrieve a dialect version of your query like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
print str(q.statement.compile(dialect=mysql.dialect()))
```

Credit where credit is due: [Blog post](http://nicolascadou.com/blog/2014/01/printing-actual-sqlalchemy-queries/)

Comment: What i really need is batch insert.Conn.execute(mutRowsInsertSql) can work,but print(mutRowsInsertSql) not.

Comment: Ok. So I would guess, that the method that `print` calls in this case, is not aware of the dialect (which is passed from the engine to the connection but nowhere to the Table classes) and uses a standard one.